# how to read list of running processes on a remote computer in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, remote-access

What can be done to know and list all running processes on a remote computer?
One idea is to have a server listening to our request on the remote machine and the other one is to use ssh.
The problem is i dont know whether there will be such a server running on the remote machine and i cannot use ssh because it needs authentication.
Is there any other way out ?

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: You must have some thing running on remote server, no matter if it is executed by your own or as OS's services.

Comment: ssh has several options for saving/specifying authentication so that you don't have to ask the user interactively, if that's why you think you can't use ssh.

Comment: yeah i know but the problem is i cannot configure ssh in any way to log in without authentication. i am just given an ip adress and have to list all process running on that ip adress.

Comment: can RPC's be used here in any way ?

Comment: that will require a daemon at the remote server supporting a RPC to get a process listing attached to some port

Answer (score 4):

If you

- cannot install a server program on the remote machine
- cannot use anything that requires authentication

then you should not be allowed to know the list of all running processes on a machine.  That request would be a security nightmare!

You can do something much simpler without (as many) security problems: scan the publicly-available ports for programs that are running.  Programs like [nmap.org](http://nmap.org/) let you know a fair bit of information about the publicly-running programs on machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past using SNMP.  I don't have the specifics in front of me, but something like "snmpwalk -v2 -c public hostname prTable" got me the process table.  I recall later configuring SNMP to generate errors when the number of processes didn't meet our specified requirement, like httpd must have at least 1 and less than 50.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the code for a remote login, `rlogin`.  You could remotely login to an account that has the privileges that you need.  Once logged in, you can fetch a list of processes.

This looks like a good application for a script rather than a C or C++ program.

Comment: The questioner already said that he cannot use authentication.